# PHP and Jquery Countdown Timer Different GMT

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime, utc

I try to build jquery countdown timer, but the end date is in mysql database with timestamp custom format

here is my saved date in database.

```
2019-01-09 12:48:29
```

That date is GMT+0000 which is UTC. But when I try to show it in javascript like below

```
var countdown = new Date("<?php echo $getDate['date_end'];?>");
console.log(countdown);
```

It will show output

```
Wed Jan 09 2019 12:48:29 GMT+0700 (GMT+07:00)
```

That's is wrong, because when I save the $getDate['date_end'] to my database is in UTC format (+0000) why it becomes GMT +0700 in javascript?

I try to convert it to UTC with this code

```
var countdown = new Date("<?php echo $getRound['date_end'];?>");
var a = countdown.toUTCString();
console.log(a);
```

but the output will give different hours

```
Wed, 09 Jan 2019 05:48:29 GMT
```

Comment: Probably because the JS date method is returning your local date/time and the server is in another location, or vice-versa.

Comment: `If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for the current date and time according to system settings for timezone offset.` [src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#JavaScript_Date_instances) You'll need to specify the timezone when you create the date in javascript

Comment: so I need to get the timezone offset then add to the time?

Comment: Use this: `countdown = new Date(countdown.getTime() - countdown.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);`

Answer (score 0):

If all of the datetime values in your database are stored in UTC, then you can create the js date object in UTC using `new Date(Date.UTC(...))` after parsing the datetime string from your database. It is not recommended to parse datetime strings with `new Date()` due to inconsistent browser implementations, so the example below includes some manual parsing and adjustment of the month value to the month indexes used in js.

```js
const s = '2019-01-09 12:48:29';
const [y, m, d, hh, mm, ss] = s.match(/\d+/g);
const utc = new Date(Date.UTC(y, m - 1, d, hh, mm, ss));
console.log('OUTPUT may vary:', utc);
console.log('UTC datestring:', utc.toUTCString());
console.log('Local datestring:', utc.toLocaleString());
```